# Make file commands

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, tr

Can anyone explain what does the characters between `-d` and `< $<` does in the following makefile command?

```
tr -d "\`~@#$%^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" < $< | ./$(ANSWER) $(STOPWORDS) | sort > $@
```

Here STOPWORDS is a file with words and ANSWER is a executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) translates or deletes characters.

Passing `-d` tells `tr` it's going to delete the `SET1` of characters it's provided

"`~@#$%^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" is the set of characters to be deleted.

`<` is a [shell redirection](http://www.lowfatlinux.com/linux-redirection.html) character

`$<` is a [one of the automatic make variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) which identifies the name of the first prerequisite

So you're deleting all characters from that specific set that are found in the first prerequisite in the given make rule.

Here's a simple example -

Makefile:

```
all:text.txt
tr -d "\`~@#$%^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" < $<
```

Now given this text.txt file:

```
$ cat text.txt
huio7&*(njkvlsan7u#%$&*(FHhnjkl
```

run the make file and you'll see:

```
$ make
tr -d "\`~@#^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" < text.txt
huio7(njkvlsan7u%$(FHhnjkl
```

The `&`, `*`, and `#` are all missing now.

The vertical bar `|` is a [pipe character](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html) which will take the output from this first command and send it to the next.

---

You asked why the `$` and `%` weren't removed, the answer is because there are some characters that Make treats special. Take a look at the actual output of the command:

```
$ make
tr -d "\`~@#^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" < text.txt
```

The line that `make` actually executed *did not* include the `$` and the `%` because `make` recognized special characters that didn't have escape characters (backslash) with them.  Example, let's escape the `%`:

New Makefile:

```
all:text.txt
tr -d "\`~@#$\%^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" < $<
```

Now running this command we see:

```
$ make
tr -d "\`~@#\%^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" < stupid_text.txt
huio7(njkvlsan7u$(FHhnjkl
```

See how the `%` showed up in the make output and the string now has removed the `%`?

Answer (score 3):

The `tr` command deletes (`-d`) all the listed characters (`` "\`~@#$%^&*=+<>{}[]|/'" `` except for the double quotes) from the file designated by `$<`.  The output goes to the answer/stopwords command, and that output is sorted into an output file.

It actually has almost nothing to do with `make` except that `$<` and `$@` are `make` variables.